# Django Rest API end-point showing unexpected numeric value instead of string

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

My each and everything working fine except an awkward issue.

At first see my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this is serializer class:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = ['id', 'author', 'title', 'body', 'category']
```

And this is my views

```
class ArticleSingle(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

and my url is

```
path('api/v1/article/<int:pk>/detail', views.ArticleSingle.as_view(), name='article-single'),
```

Everything else working fine but the problem is, when i hit in url to get article details, it show everything else good except an issue and that is, author name and category name returning a numeric value..

below are unexpected result:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 2,
    "author": 1,
    "title": "i am title",
    "body": "i am body",
    "category": 1
}
```

Please look closely on `author` and `category` , it returns me numeric value, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because in your `serializer` you aren't point to witch field shown in `ForeignKey` field of your models instance.if you don't setup ForeignKey's field so in serializer will just show you 'id' . you can use HyperLinkModel as [this doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield) :

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,        
    )
    category = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,        
    )

    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'title', 'body', 'category') #  use '(' instead of '['
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to get ID or pk in json response for a foreignkey related field of an object .
if you want to have string instead you need to edit your serializers field like this

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
author = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
category = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model =  Article
    fields = ['id', 'author', 'title', 'body', 'category']
```